# How to speed up process for refreshing Document ID link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-id

I've been trying to figure out how Document ID links work and was successful in generating it for my documents. However, I've noticed that if I move a file to a folder within other folders (in the same site collection), it takes around 30 minutes to an hour before the Document ID link works again. I assume this is because the original file path is still updating on the backend with the file path where the file has been moved to.

Is there a job that I can look into to speed up this process/speed up the pushing of the data or correct file path for the file I moved to a different folder?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the server side issue and there is no exact solution to speed up process for refreshing Document ID link.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a Microsoft Flow on the target location (library/folder). Once the file is moved from a source folder to the target folder - that flow should be triggered automatically which will read the **Document ID** value from the source folder location and update the **Document ID** value in the target location. This automation process will automatically update the **Document ID** immediately.

You can refer to the below articles how to update the metadata values using the Microsoft Flow:

- [Flow that Updates a Column in a Sharepoint online Doc Set](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Flow-that-Updates-a-Column-in-a-Sharepoint-online-Doc-Set/m-p/315854#M33758)
- [Workaround to update SharePoint document metadata custom columns](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Workaround-to-update-SharePoint-document-metadata-custom-columns/td-p/44428)